# Change text on hover jquery to random answer

Tags: jquery

I am looking to recreate something similar to the logo on [marieforleo.com](https://www.marieforleo.com/)

When you hold you mouse over the logo, the text changes.
Then when you move off, it changes back.
BUT each time you move over, it changes to a DIFFERENT random text.

Any ideas how this was created ? I am guessing with JQuery

many thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Using Math.Random() function.The random() method returns a random number from 0 (inclusive) up to but not including 1 (exclusive).

**Html:-**

```
<span id="originalText">Hello,Dhiren</span>
<span id="newText">ExampleText</span>
```

**JavaScript:-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var originalText = $( "#originalText" ).text();
    $( "#originalText" ).mouseenter(function() {
        var text = '';
               var quotes = new Array("Softwre Engineer", "Front End Developer", "Back End developer", "Database Administrator");

         var randno = Math.floor ( Math.random() * quotes.length );

            text += quotes[randno];

        $( "#newText" ).text( text );
    });
    $( "#originalText" ).mouseleave(function() {
        $( "#newText" ).text( originalText );
    });
})
```

Working [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirenpateldev/saj6brn8/) Here..

Hope Its Work !!
Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Thanks Dhiren, Do you know how I would also add animation to the text, so rather than just appear, I would like it to look like typewriting.
i.e. text appears 1 letter after the other from left, then disappears one letter at a time from the right. Many thanks - could we use - https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it uses the mouseenter() / mouseleave() to call a function which uses the Math.random to select a text from an array of such texts and set it in the HTML.